# PC hangs during post when webcam is plugged in

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, webcam, post

My PC keeps hanging during POST, just before identifying the amount of RAM, anytime I have my webcam plugged in. If I unplug the webcam, it will unhang and continue to boot up just fine. It also occasionally locks up windows if I have the webcam plugged in.

[image]

- I have the latest BIOS for the mobo, 2.20.
- The webcam is plugged into a powered Macally USB hub, so it should be getting plenty of juice.
- I recently replaced the power supply, thinking it might be the cause, before I identified the webcam as the culprit.
- I tried disabling legacy USB support.
- I tried removing USB from the boot order.

Motherboard: ASRock 4coreDual-SATA2
Webcam: Ausdom AW310

How can I make these two play nice with each other?

Comment: have a look here and see if this post may be of some help. http://superuser.com/questions/659710/a-computer-that-fails-to-boot-if-certain-usb-devices-are-plugged-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really there are only two options here. Either the BIOS is buggy as suggested in the link provided in the comment section by @NetworkKingPin, or else the USB webcam doesn't meet USB specifications as built and is causing a short.

I'm personally in favor of the latter interpretation, as it would also explain why the webcam is occasionally freezing your system during Windows operation.

The test of this theory is simple - get another webcam and test things with that. If the problem persists, there may be a short occurring with the hub, or the port in which the hub is installed. Changing hubs and moving ports may also resolve the issue.