# PC BIOS freezes when USB webcam is plugged in

Tags: boot, usb, bios, freeze, webcam

I have an HP Compaq 6000 running Ubuntu 14.04, and when I plug in my Logitech HD Pro C920 Web Cam and try to boot, the computer gets stuck on the BIOS.

In fact, if I go into BIOS settings, then plug in the webcam, the BIOS freezes immediately.

I have changed the boot order, disabling USB completely from the boot sequence. I don't have an option for legacy USB support. It doesn't matter whether the cam is plugged into the front or back ports. There doesn't appear to be a BIOS update on HP's website.

The Exact model is HP Compaq 6000 Pro SFF PC Pentium Dual Core E6300 2.80GHz: 
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01865797

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PC hangs during post when webcam is plugged in](https://superuser.com/questions/1062430/pc-hangs-during-post-when-webcam-is-plugged-in)

Comment: Please post exact model of 6000 please.

Comment: @Moab Edited above

Comment: Does the cam cause the same issue on on other Windows PC's?

Comment: I am only running Ubuntu, but I tried it on 3 computers and the other two booted fine.